# I need to define a group_id to a range of rows that have header and footer

Tags: sql-server

Everything beetwhen the 'type' 0 and 9 must have the same group number. You can undestand better if you look the images i attached.

the query that generates the data:

```
select
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS id
    ,'type' = SUBSTRING(content, 433, 1)
    ,'group' = CONVERT(BIGINT,NULL)
into #myData
from    
    #import
```

[image: My data]

[image: The result i need]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative count of the `1`s:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
from t;
```

Note:  The terminating "9" doesn't play a role here.  It seems superfluous.  Also, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you really need a column that specifies the ordering.